# how to find Next key using foreach in SortedDictionary in C#

Tags: c#, foreach, sorteddictionary

I have a sorted dictionary which has stored strings as keys and values.
And I am checking the value of each key with some conditions.

```
void sample()
{
  SortedDictionary<string, string>.KeyCollection keyColl = clrDatesSelectedSortedDict.Keys;
  foreach (string key in keyColl)
   {
     if(chckstring = key)
      value = clrDatesSelectedSortedDict[key];
   }
 }
```

actually in if condition i want to know the next key as well. How to get the next key value?

And one more question, is it possible to use for loop instead of foreach for sortedDictionary in C#?

Please help me any one of the above.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like

```
Public Sub TestLoopForeachKey()
    Dim sd As New SortedDictionary(Of String, String)
    For i = 0 To sd.Count
        Dim nextIndex As Integer = i + 1
        If nextIndex < sd.Count Then
            ' Exists another posterior key
            Dim currentKey As String = sd(i)
            Dim nextKey As String = sd(nextIndex)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Your attempt at index using `sd(i)` will not work because the key is `String`, not `Integer`.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like i dont have option strict on in my unit tests, just wanted to show a way to do it ;P

Answer (score 0):

Sure, using the Ling extension ElementAt():

```
void sample()
{
    SortedDictionary<String, String>.KeyCollection keyColl = clrDatesSelectedSortedDict.Keys;
    for (Int32 i = 0; i < keyColl.Count; i++)
    {
        if (chckstring == keyColl.ElementAt(i).Key)
        {
            value = clrDatesSelectedSortedDict[keyColl.ElementAt(i).Key];
            if ((i + 1) < keyColl.Count)
                nextValue = clrDatesSelectedSortedDict[keyColl.ElementAt(i + 1).key];
        }
    }
}
```